# Regular Expression in RewriteRule breaks in MAMP

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, mamp

I just switched from XAMPP to MAMP and now this rewrite rule does not work anymore

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{6}+)/?$ includes/redirect.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

In the Appache error log:

```
[Mon Nov 22 13:59:24 2010] [alert] [client 172.xx.xx.x] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/.htaccess: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^([0-9]{6}+)/?$'
```

Any idea's? My other rule (from redirect.php) works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{6})-.*?\.html$ templates/default/index.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [0-9]{6}+
```

This is an odd fragment that I suspect is the issue. You're saying exactly 6 digits, then saying one-or-more as well?

What did you want to be matched?

Comment: I want to match a 6 digit number. myapp/012345 to myapp/includes/redirect.php?ref=012345

Comment: Then you don't need the +. Try removing it.

Comment: ah, one more? No sometimes they also use: myapp/012345/ (extra slash)